# Event triggering (hover and multiple click) is not working properly in the order they are called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm creating a code that can recursively cancel the friend request on Facebook.

The action flow are as follows:

1. list of friend request

[image: list of friend request]

2. cancel button context after hover

[image: cancel button context after]

3. Final Cancel request button

[image: Final Cancel request button]

> I'm using following logic to perform the action:

```
var offset = 0;
$(".FriendRequestOutgoing.enableFriendListFlyout.outgoingButton.enableFriendListFlyout").each(function(){
    var xxx=$(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        xxx.trigger("hover");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".uiMenuItem.FriendListCancel .itemLabel").trigger("click");
            setTimeout(function(){
               $(".layerConfirm.uiOverlayButton").trigger("click");
            },1000);
        },1000);                    
      }, 4500 + Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+ offset);    
   offset += 4500 + Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
});
```

> Note: I have already added jQuery Script to it's body